# Передать Аргумент в wpf программу

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно запустив из окна WinForms передать программе на WPF аргументы.

Comment: Если верить ответу ниже, то единственный выход - сохранять аргументы в файл, и затем читать их при запуске второй программы.

Comment: Какие аргументы? аргументы командной строки?

Comment: Если вы про аргументы командной строки, то в любом приложении их можно достать из `Environment.CommandLine`, правда парсить придется руками.

Comment: @rdorn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, а слона-то я и не заметил =)

Comment: Всем спасибо, сделал передачу параметров через буфер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

эти функциональности ограничены в ОС для безопасности.если в обладатель этих двух программ тогда можете организовать передачи данных из одной программы в другой с помощью .net remoting (WCF).это называется "Маршалинг".это подобие сериализации между двумя программ.